# slide an image icon underneath a list item on a nav menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I feel like I must be missing something, because I can't find anything about this issue when searching, even though I know I've seen this technique on several websites.

I have a horizontal nav menu near the bottom of my screen. Basically 4 items listed along the bottom right.  Don't have the code in front of me, but from memory the code is something like this:

```
`<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Schedule</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>`
```

For styling, I have:

```
li{
    margin-top: 52vh;
    float: right;
}
```

The site is kitten-themed. What I want is, when I hover over one of the list items, e.g. Schedule, a pawprint icon I have will slide in from the left side to where the word Schedule is, and at the same time the word Schedule will move vertically so that the pawprint is centered underneath the word Schedule, but approximately lined up with the other list items that haven't moved.  Then, when you hover over another list item, e.g. Contact, the word Contact lifts up and the pawprint moves underneath it, while the word schedule sinks down to its previous place in the line.  In other words, the pawprint moves to show which item you're selecting.

I have the part where the word lifts up working (somewhat). I have two different codes I have used, with both seeming to produce the same effect. The first is CSS:

```
li:hover{
    margin-top: 48vh;
}
```

The other is jQuery:

```
$("li").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("margin-top", "48vh")
}, function {$(this).css("margin-top", "52vh")
```

});

I do have a flickering problem, where when I hover the word moves up then immediately moves back down if I don't move the mouse up to cover it, so it jumps up and down.

As far as the pawprint, I tried adding

```
background-image: url("pawprint");
```

to my li:hover, along with a display: block. I also tried adding the image to the jQuery.css. With the jQuery the pawprint shows up right behind the word at the 48vh level, not underneath the word.

Don't know if you need any other info, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Requirement should be possible using `css` `:hover` and `animation`. To animate text you can set an element as child of `<li>` with `.textContent` set to `"Schedule"`.

Comment: It's really hard to make sense of what you're trying to do without a demo, but in general, you don't want to change the margin of something on hover, because when the thing moves, you're no longer hovering over it, creating that "flicker." Depends on what you're trying to do exactly as to what would be a better solution, but you could try changing padding instead of margin, which should not flicker that way. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpXxpO

Answer (score 1):

You can set text within `span` element as child node of `li` element; use `css` `:before` pseudo element at `li` element with `content` set to `url()` function with image URL as parameter, `opacity` set to `0`. Set `transition` of `span` child of `li` to `top 1s ease-in-out`.

At `:hover` of `li:before`, set `opacity` to `1`, begin `animation` of `margin-left` from `-100%` to `0%` of image set at `content`. Set `top` of `span` to `-25px`, or half the `height` of image set at `content`, to move text above image which slides in from left.

```css
li {
  margin-top: 52vh;
  float: right;
  padding: 8px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

li span {
  position: relative;
  transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
}

li:before {
  content: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

li:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: slide 1s;
}

li:hover span {
  top: -25px;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><span>Contact</span></li>
    <li><span>Schedule</span></li>
    <li><span>About</span></li>
    <li><span>Home</span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! Couple of questions. First, the paw print has a smaller width than the words it's under at any time (Home, About, Schedule, Contact), and it's aligned with the left side of the word. Is there a way to center it under each word? Second, the paw print slides in from the left side of the screen, which is what I want for the user's first hover, but then for each subsequent hover I would like the paw print to go from the previous hover to the next hover, rather than starting over again from the left side.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The first additional question should be possible. The second additional question appears to be different than requirement described at OP. You can adjust approach at Answer to fine tune the rendered effects

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to understand the code you gave me so I can modify it. What I'm having trouble understanding is how the pawprint finds its way below the list item. I thought the :before would put the pawprint ahead of, or to the left of, the list item. How does it get to below the list item (which I do want)? Also, once it's under a list item, is there a way to grab its position under the list item and use jQuery to change the position to the next item hovered over, so that the pawprint slides from one list item to another? I would like to get the position in vh so as to be responsive.

Comment: The `css` `:before` pseudo element of `li` element has `position` set to `absolute`. At `:hover` of `li` `animation` of `li:before` begins at `-100%`, to left of viewport, and concludes at `0%`. It should be possible to adjust `margin-left` property to position of previous `li` if current hovered `li` is not first. From perspective here, if you have issue solving, that would be an interesting `css` or `javascript` follow up Question; where all details of expected result are included within body of original Question.